# how can i install CentOS 6 without the gui?

Tags: linux, shell, centos

i just downloaded the centos 6 live cd and i tried installing it on virtually and i am never prompted to install centos with/without gui and its all automated. what happends is after i am booted into the live cd on desktop and i click to install it all is automated after that. how can i install shell only? or just use what i have and to always boot into shell and never see the gui?

thanks

Comment: I have installed shell only install for web server with plain dvds... that is **not** live version (cd or dvd)...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The CentOS 6.0 live CD does not provide any customisation options, it is intended to install a full desktop.  To do a server install, choose the minimal or normal CD/DVD from the Centos site.

To do the installation using a text installer, when you see the boot menu for the normal CD, you'll see "install or upgrade existing system"

Press TAB, and go to the end of the command line containing `vmlinuz`, at the end add the word `text`.

Note that this is right at the beginning of booting from the CD.

Note that the text based installer is pretty basic and does not give you much in the way of partitioning options.

Comment: Sorry I may have misunderstood this - you mean you want to install Centos without X and the Desktop, you just want a server installation?

Comment: yes, just shell

Answer (score 6):

In the case of using VMWare Workstation, you have to create the virtual machine first and then run the install of CentOS separate from creating the VM.  If you do both together, VMWare will use "Easy Install" which means an unintended install that includes every option/package.  If you make the virtual machine first and then do a manual install from a DVD, you have options including installation with the gui options.

Answer (score 5):

CentOS do a minimal version, this doesn't come with any kind of GUI.

http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/x86_64/