# CentOS liveCD bootup failure

Tags: boot, centos, livecd, grab

The failure is like this:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32-279.5.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
[] ? panic+0xa0/0x168
[] ? do_exit+0x862/0x870
[] ? fput+0x25/x130
[] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
[] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
[] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

And I tried the following solutions:

1) SELINUX=disabled [reference](http://johanlouwers.blogspot.com/2013/02/linux-kernel-panic-init-not-tainted.html)

2) Press TAB, and go to the end of the command line containing `vmlinuz`, at the end add the word `text`. [reference](https://superuser.com/questions/365118/how-can-i-install-centos-6-without-the-gui)

None of the above works.

BTW, I tried modifying the boot command by pressing `TAB` on splash screen and added some errors in it. The boot up process is exactly as it was, which means the error in it doesn't make a difference. So I'm afraid if the boot command doesn't work at all.

I'm new to centos. So I could have made some stupid mistakes.

P.S. I can install that live CD on a VMbox on Ubuntu. But when I use it to boot my real machine, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

How old is the computer?

1. The kernel might be lacking the drivers needed for the hardware.
2. The hardware might be bad like the memory
3. The CD/DVD might need to be burned again

Comment: The system can definitely read my USB since I can see the splash screen stored in the USB drive. However it broke down at some point during boot. I can see the circular centOS progress bar

Comment: Also I re-burned my USB ended up in no luck

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the PC is newer - you may have to enable legacy boot options(which is the case with my Dell R15 when trying to use a bootable CD or USB)

Comment: I just checked my BIOS and it was enabled.